# java how to change tint make image redscale

Tags: java

i am new to progrraming and have started learning java recently.
i was trying to write some code but was not able to find the exact way to do it so i came here!
now about the code.. this code is basicaly a gray scale converter and it works i have imported a library and am working with that.howevr i wanted to make the images red insted of gray so it looks exactly like a gray scale image but has red instead of gray...

```
import edu.duke.*;
public class Grayscaleconverter {
 public ImageResource makeGray(ImageResource inImage){
     ImageResource outImage=new     ImageResource(inImage.getWidth(),inImage.getHeight());
     for (Pixel pixel:outImage.pixels()){
         Pixel inPixel=inImage.getPixel(pixel.getX(),pixel.getY());

     double red=(inPixel.getRed()*0.25); 
     double blue=(inPixel.getBlue()*0.25); 
     double green=(inPixel.getGreen()*0.25);
     pixel.setRed(red);
     pixel.setGreen(green);
     pixel.setBlue(blue);
    }

     return outImage;
    }

     public void testGray(){
         ImageResource ir= new ImageResource();
         ImageResource red=makeGray(ir);
         red.draw();
```

To make an image gray you just have to take all the averages of every pixel and set red,green and blue to that average. but here i have tried to change the tint
but the first error is in pixel.setred(red) it says possible lossy conversion from double to int i have tried writing double inside the bracket pixel.setred((double red)) but its not working. also could you please tell me if the way i am wrting my code will give me my desired output? if not anyone could write the code and explain.. please make it simple sorry to take your time.

thank you.
p.s outimage is the result and inimage is the image that has to be covnverted

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting? Thank you.

Comment: the first error i am getting is in the pixel.setred(red) line and it says possible lossy conversion from double to int. i hve tried changing my variable red,green,and blue to doubles but  it still shows the error at the pixel.setred(red) line